# Bootstrap 3 Collapse show state with Chevron icon

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using the core example taken from the Bootstrap 3 Javascript [examples page for Collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-examples),
 I have been able to show the state of collapse using chevron icons.

I have this working using:

```js
$('#accordion .accordion-toggle').click(function (e) {
    var chevState = $(e.target).siblings("i.indicator").toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up');
    $("i.indicator").not(chevState).removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-down").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-up");
});
```

This works (not fully tested in all browsers), but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution to this?

Ideally I'd like to use the core function, but I'm not sure how to achieve the same results with it.

```js
$('#accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
    //do something...
})
```

Here's a working version in **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Flocktome/R6EAW/10/)**.

Comment: Hi, in this example, how do i make the entire heading a hyperlink instead of just the text.  in other words, when i click on the heading panel, not just the text, i want to display to toggle.  how do i do that?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024218/bootstrap-3-collapse-change-chevron-icon-on-click/

Comment: @user1447718 Here's a fiddle doing exactly that: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gYa3/221/)
I wanted the whole header clickable too, so I combined some solutions I found across SO (including this one).

Comment: Similar to dperish, I did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024218/bootstrap-3-collapse-change-chevron-icon-on-click/)

Answer (score 247):

For the following HTML (from [Bootstrap 3 examples](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)):

```css
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle:after {
    /* symbol for "opening" panels */
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';  /* essential for enabling glyphicon */
    content: "\e114";    /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
    float: right;        /* adjust as needed */
    color: grey;         /* adjust as needed */
}
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
    /* symbol for "collapsed" panels */
    content: "\e080";    /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Visual effect:

[image: bootstrap3 chevron icon on accordion]

Comment: This works well ... here's a jsFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/3gYa3/

Comment: Nice solution biggates. I think I'll adopt his method instead of using Javascript. Older browsers can live without the chevron. Well done

Comment: In the fiddle, all chevrons point down initially. Is there an easy fix for that?

Comment: I don't see a pure CSS solution for the initial state; the problem here is that bootstrap doesn't add the class "collapsed" to the link until you collapse at least one (even if they're all collapsed to start). Then it simply removes that class from the link for "open." So since "open" and "default" have the same class, there's no good pure CSS solution. Ideally this would be fixed by modifying bootstrap's javascript to add an "open" class to differentiate. Until then, live with it, or use JS from one of the other answers.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but to answer Carl's issue - if you add the class of "collapsed" on all the anchor tags with "accordion-toggle", your issues goes away.... So have "accordion-toggle collapsed". JQuery will then add and remove the classes when it needs to.

Comment: Works great! I took the liberty of creating this in bootply: http://www.bootply.com/O9KrlN6pnp

Comment: I modified this example so that the whole header is clickable. One minor bug I did notice is that the text at the far right side of each panel is "pushed" a little until after the slide open/close animation completes. If anyone knows how to fix that, please do.
Here's the fiddle: [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gYa3/221/)

Comment: Thanks for this CSS hint, I personally used only the `right-chevron` with an animated rotation `-90deg`

Comment: Made by links inside of .panel-title block elements, which allows you to click on the entire width of the panel title / heading area.

Comment: The source of the "pushed" bug is the float:left in the css. However, I don't see a simple solution/alternative.

Comment: Thanks, additionally for  **Plus**: `\002b` and **Minus** : `\2212` , hope helps.

Comment: Although this solution works, it still doesn't solve/explain controlling the initial state of the chevron's. I have a reply to this post below that goes into detail on how to control the initial state.

Comment: I suggest to `<a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">` test it here http://jsfiddle.net/3LLeayog/

Answer (score 57):

You could use this kind of code :

```js
function toggleChevron(e) {
    $(e.target)
        .prev('.panel-heading')
        .find('i.indicator')
        .toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up');
}
$('#accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
$('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
```

=> Working [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/R6EAW/12/)

Comment: That's a much better way zessx, well done mate. This is the first clean solution I've seen since Bootstrap 3 launched.

Comment: You could use also `$('#accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse shown.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);`

Comment: If you prefer the arrow to move at the beginning of the collapse instead of at  the end you can use ```$('#accordion').on('hide.bs.collapse show.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);``` instead

Comment: This works very well. How do I make the icon toggle faster?

Comment: @RachelS The suggestion from Will Parker makes it faster.

Answer (score 21):

To improve upon the answer with the most upticks, some of you may have noticed on the initial load of the page that the chevrons all point in the same direction. This is corrected by adding the class "collapsed" to elements that you want to load collapsed.

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3gYa3/585/

Answer (score 12):

Improvement on Bludream's answer:

You can definitely use FontAwesome!

Make sure to include "collapsed" along with "panel-heading" class. The "collapsed" class is not included until you click on the panel so you want to include the "collapsed" class in order to display the correct chevron (i.e., chevron-right is displayed when collapsed and chevron-down when open).

HTML

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOrderItems1">Products 1 <i class="chevron fa fa-fw" ></i></div>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseOrderItems1">
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.panel-heading .chevron:after {
    content: "\f078";   
}
.panel-heading.collapsed .chevron:after {
    content: "\f054";   
}
```

Also, it is a good practice to create a new class instead of using an existing class.

See Codepen for example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPxOJX

Comment: And with fontawesome 4 : fa-chevron-up for the element and 
.collapsed .fa-chevron-up:before { content: "\f077";} for class

Answer (score 11):

Thanks to biggates and steakpi.
As answer of question Dreamonic, I made a little changes to make all headers clickable (not only title string and gluphs) and took off underline from link.
To force an icons appear on same line I added h4 at the end of CSS instructions. Here is the modified code:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">      
        <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          <h4 class="panel-title">Collapsible Group Item #1</h4>
        </a>      
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">      
        <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          <h4 class="panel-title">Collapsible Group Item #2</h4>
        </a>      
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">      
        <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          <h4 class="panel-title">Collapsible Group Item #3</h4>
        </a>      
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the modified CSS:

```
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle h4:after {
    /* symbol for "opening" panels */
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';  
    content: "\e114";    
    float: right;        
    color: grey;        
    overflow: no-display;
}
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle.collapsed h4:after {
    /* symbol for "collapsed" panels */
    content: "\e080";    
}
a.accordion-toggle{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: works fine, remove thin dotted line when click on title and focus via a.accordion-toggle:focus{
    outline: none !important;
}

Answer (score 10):

I know this is old but since it's now 2018, I thought I would reply making it better by simplifying the code and enhancing the user experience by making the chevron rotate based on collapsed or not. I'm using FontAwesome however. Here's the CSS:

```
a[data-toggle="collapse"] .rotate {
   -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
   -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
   transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
   -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
   transform: rotate(90deg);
}
a[data-toggle="collapse"].collapsed .rotate {
   -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
   transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

Here's the HTML for the panel section:

```
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right rotate"></i>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I use bootstraps pull-right to pull the chevron all the way to the right of the panel heading which should be full width and responsive. The CSS does all of the animation work and rotates the chevron based on if the panel is collapsed or not.  Simple.

Comment: If I could upvote this multiple times, I would. Its an awesome solution to the problem with a nice animation and everything. Cheers!

Answer (score 8):

Here's a couple of pure css helper classes which lets you handle any kind of toggle content right in your html.

It works with any element you need to switch. Whatever your layout is you just put it inside a couple of elements with the .if-collapsed and .if-not-collapsed classes within the toggle element.

The only catch is that you have to make sure you put the desired initial state of the toggle. If it's initially closed, then put a **collapsed** class on the toggle.

It also requires the **:not** selector, it doesn't work on IE8.

HTML example:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample">
  <!--You can put any valid html inside these!-->
  <span class="if-collapsed">Open</span>
  <span class="if-not-collapsed">Close</span>
</a>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="well">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Less version:

```
[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    &.collapsed .if-not-collapsed {
         display: none;
    }
    &:not(.collapsed) .if-collapsed {
         display: none;
    }
}
```

CSS version:

```
[data-toggle="collapse"].collapsed .if-not-collapsed {
  display: none;
}
[data-toggle="collapse"]:not(.collapsed) .if-collapsed {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

working simple example

- get the body condition shown/hidden
- get to its parent att
- get find icon
- change icon

[enter simple](http://jsfiddle.net/diffintact/BVmUL/46/)

**HTML**:

```html
<body>
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#jai">Jai</a>
        </div>
        <div id="jai" class="accordion-body collapse in">
            <div>
                <div class="accordion-inner">body content 1</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">jai2</a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
            <div>
                <div class="accordion-inner">body content 2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse3">jai3</a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse3" class="accordion-body collapse">
            <div>
                <div class="accordion-inner">body content 3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
$('div.accordion-body').on('shown', function () {
    $(this).parent("div").find(".icon-chevron-down")
           .removeClass("icon-chevron-down").addClass("icon-chevron-up");
});

$('div.accordion-body').on('hidden', function () {
    $(this).parent("div").find(".icon-chevron-up")
           .removeClass("icon-chevron-up").addClass("icon-chevron-down");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

or... you can just put some style like this.

```
.panel-title a.collapsed {
     background: url(../img/arrow_right.png) center right no-repeat;
}
.panel-title a {
     background: url(../img/arrow_down.png) center right no-repeat;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJjrQN

Answer (score 2):

One-liner.

```
i.fa.fa-chevron-right.collapse.in { transform: rotate(180deg); }
```

In this example it's being used to group collapsible table rows.  The only thing you need to do is add the target class name (my-collapse-name) to your icon:

```
<tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".my-collapse-name">
    <th><i class="fa fa-chevron-right my-collapse-name"></span></th>
    <th>Master Row - Title</th>
</tr>
<tr class="collapse my-collapse-name">
    <td></td>
    <td>Detail Row - Content</td>
</tr>
```

You could accomplish the same with Bootstrap's native caret class by using `<span class='caret my-collapse-name'></span>` and `span.caret.collapse.in { transform: rotate(90deg); }`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using **font awesome**! and wanted a panel to be collapsible

```
        <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOrderItems"><i class="fa fa-chevron fa-fw" ></i> products</div>

                <div class="collapse in" id="collapseOrderItems">
                            ....
                </div>
        </div>
```

and the css

```
.panel-heading .fa-chevron:after {
    content: "\f078";   
}
.panel-heading.collapsed .fa-chevron:after {
    content: "\f054";   
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Angular seems to cause issues with the JavaScript-based approaches here ( at least the ones I've tried ) . I found this solution here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/987311/Collapsible-Responsive-Master-Child-Grid-Using-Ang . The gist of it is to use `data-ng-click` on the toggle button and make the method to change the button in the controller using the `$scope` context .

I guess I could provide more detail...
my buttons are set to the glyphicon of the initial state of the div they collapse ( glyphicon-chevron-right == collapsed div ) .

page.html:

```
<div class="title-1">
    <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#panel-{{ p_idx }}" class="dropdown-toggle title-btn glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" data-ng-click="collapse($event)"></button>
</div>
<div id="panel-{{ p_idx }}" class="collapse sect">
    ...
</div>
```

controllers.js:

```
.controller('PageController', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.collapse = function (event) {
        $(event.target).toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-right");
    };
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use this with panels only (not accordeon), try this code:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="collapse-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Panel heading with title</a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseExample" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
            Panel content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

I wanted a pure html approach as I wanted to collapse and expand html that was added on the fly via a template! I came up with this...

https://jsfiddle.net/3mguht2y/1/

```
var noJavascript = ":)";
```

Which might be of use to someone :)