# Bootstrap 3 collapse can have multiple panels open after programmatically opening a panel

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem with bootstrap 3 collapse, after opening a panel programmatically it is possible to keep another panel open while reopening the first panel.

My **HTML**:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn showpanel">Show panel 3</button>
<button type="button" class="btn hidepanel">Hide panel 3</button>
<button type="button" class="btn openpanel">Open panel 3</button>
<button type="button" class="btn closepanel">Close panel 3</button>
<hr/>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel1">Panel 1</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="panel1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Contents panel 1
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel2">Panel 2</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="panel2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Contents panel 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel3">Panel 3</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="panel3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Contents panel 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And some **JavaScript**:

```js
$(".hidepanel").on("click", function() {
    $("#panel3").parent().hide();
});
$(".showpanel").on("click", function() {
    $("#panel3").parent().show();
});
$(".openpanel").on("click", function() {
    $("#panel3").collapse('show');
});
$(".closepanel").on("click", function() {
    $("#panel3").collapse('hide');
});
```

## [My jsfiddle that demonstrates this issue](http://jsfiddle.net/US9yQ/3/)

To reproduce:

1. Click the button 'Open panel 3'.
2. Click 'Panel 2' to open it. So far no problems.
3. Click 'Panel 3' to open it again. Panel 2 remains open!

So opening a panel programmatically seems to mess up bootstraps internal registration about panel states? I don't see anything visibly wrong with the 'state change' of the third panel (it's class changes from 'collapse' to 'in' and back as you would expect).

Answer (score 28):

You can create a handler for the collapse `show` event which occurs just before any panels are displayed.

Add this to ensure any other open panels are closed before the selected one is shown:

```js
$('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('#accordion .in').collapse('hide');
});
```

### [Bootply demo](http://bootply.com/85167)

You can read more about the `collapse` events here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Comment: This certainly works, but I wonder if this is a known bootstrap bug that we are working around here. I'm gonna check the buglist.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. Your buttons are 'manually' controlling the accordions usual open/close behavior which may be the desired behavior in some cases.

Comment: If I understand the collapse widget well, my html is supposed to make the accordion to act as 'one panel open at max' because of the data-parent attribute I used, you can also create a 'multiple open panel' accordion by using the data-target attribute (for example see http://plnkr.co/edit/OxbVII?p=preview). So I think if I manually open or close a panel, the accordion should follow this principle.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that when you have nested accordions and have this handler on the outer accordion, it still gets fired from event on the inner accordion.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is due to the way you are changing the open panel.  Rather than using the 'show' feature you need to fire the click event on the appropriate panel link.  For example with an accordion with an id "accordion", with three panels, if you want to show the 2 panel then use:

```
$("a[href=#accordion-2]").click()
```

Or whatever ID you have given your second panel (I use twitterboostrapmvc so the panel ids are auto-generated from the accordion ID).

Comment: This is also the workaround recommended in the bootstrap github issue for this behaviour https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9933

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using `data-target` attributes to control the accordion (rather than the `href` attribute), this is an adaptation of ProfNimrod's answer which will click the relevant element if the target is currently hidden. (Note that the `if` check relies on setting up the accordion with the `collapsed` class applied by default, which I find useful anyway to take advantage of [using css to put a chevron icon on the accordions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18568997/4051181)).

```
var expandAccordion = function() {
    var header = $('[data-target="#accordion-0"]');
    if (header.hasClass('collapsed')) {
        header.click();
    }
}
```