# Bootstrap 3 Collapse - Change of icon with change of classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/krish7878/6xpdeLa6/

There are two div's .panel-heading and .panel-collapse. If .panel-collapse has class 'in' then a icon has to be added to .panel-heading. I have the jquery for it but the problem is the icons do not update when the class changes.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="sub-menu-1 panel-group" id="accordion">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                FASHION
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div><!-- /.panel-heading -->
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <ul class="list-normal sub-menu-list">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                        Man
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                        Women
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                        Children
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                        Infants
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul><!-- /.sub-menu-list -->
        </div>
    </div><!-- /#collapseOne -->
</div><!-- /.panel -->
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
                SPORTS
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div><!-- /.panel-heading -->
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <ul class="list-normal sub-menu-list">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                        Sports Gear
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                        Sports Shoes
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                        Discounted Stuff
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                        Other Option
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                        Other Option 2
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                        Other Option 3
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul><!-- /.sub-menu-list -->
        </div><!-- /.panel-body -->
    </div><!-- /#collapseTwo -->
</div><!-- /.panel -->
```

JS Code:

```
$(".panel-heading + .collapse:not(.in)").prev().append("<i class='fa fa-plus'></i>");
$(".panel-heading + .collapse.in").prev().append("<i class='fa fa-minus'></i>");
```

I think the code needs to be run each time the class changes but I'm not sure how to do it, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you should consider toggle for this --> [SO Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325779/bootstrap-3-collapse-show-state-with-chevron-icon)

Comment: Thank you Karthick, I had a look at this question before, I wanted the plus and minus for my design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Husen/6xpdeLa6/35/)

You can do like following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".panel-heading + .collapse:not(.in)").prev().append("<i class='fa fa-plus'></i>");
    $(".panel-heading + .collapse.in").prev().append("<i class='fa fa-minus'></i>");
    $('.panel-heading a').click(function(){ 
        $('.panel').find('.collapse.in').prev().find("i").addClass("fa-plus").removeClass("fa-minus");
        $(this).parents('.panel-heading').find("i.fa-plus").removeClass("fa-plus").addClass("fa-minus");
        $(this).parents('.panel').find('.collapse.in').prev().find("i.fa-minus").removeClass("fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus");
    });
});
```