# bootstrap collapse event hidden.bs.collapse not being detected

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an angular application that uses bootstrap collapse element.
I've created a directive called accordion-list that host the collapsible elements.
Then, to listen to the events, i've used jquery event delegation.
For some reason, my application can't detect when the bootstrap fires the [hidden.bs.collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-usage) event.
Here is my code:

```
//app.js
    'use strict';

(function () {
    var provasNaoIdentificadas = angular.module("provasNaoIdentificadas", [
        'restClient'
    ]);

    provasNaoIdentificadas.controller("accordionCtrl", ["$scope", "ListaInscricao", function($scope, ListaInscricao){
        $scope.inscricao = {
            "Secretaria": ""
        };

        $("accordion-list").on("hidden.bs.collapse shown.bs.collapse", ".collapse", function (event) {
            if ($(this).hasClass("in")) {
                $(this).prev().find(".glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-minus");
                $(this).prev().find("span.pull-right.text-muted").removeClass("expandir fechar").addClass("fechar");
            } else {
                $(this).prev().find(".glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-plus");
                $(this).prev().find("span.pull-right.text-muted").removeClass("expandir fechar").addClass("expandir");
            }

            console.log(1, this, event); // i have detected the problem by interpreting 
        });

        ListaInscricao.get({"id": 1}, function(data){
            if (data.Sucesso) {
                $scope.inscricao = data.Dados;
            } else {
                // toastr
            }
        });
    }]);

    provasNaoIdentificadas.directive('accordionList', function() {
        return {
            "restrict": "E",
            "templateUrl": "partials/accordion.html"
        };
    });
})();
```

Help you guys can help me. Thanks in advance. :)

**EDIT**

Here's my files:

index.html:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="provasNaoIdentificadas">
    <head>
        <title>Hábile: Inscrição De Escolas Públicas Para Provas Não Identificadas</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/rest-client.js"></script>
        <style>
            .panel-heading {
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            .panel-heading .panel-title span.pull-right.text-muted {
                font-size: 10px;
            }

            .panel-heading .panel-title span.pull-right.text-muted.expandir:before {
                content: "clique para expandir";
            }

            .panel-heading .panel-title span.pull-right.text-muted.fechar:before {
                content: "clique para fechar";
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="well text-justify">
                <h3>Formul&aacute;rio de Inscri&ccedil;&atilde;o H&aacute;bile 2014</h3>
            </div>
            <div ng-controller="accordionCtrl">
                <h2 id="nomeSecretaria">{{ inscricao.Secretaria }}</h2>
                <accordion-list></accordion-list>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Salvar Inscrição</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning">Finalizar Inscrição</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

partials/accordion.html

```
<!-- partials/accordion.html -->
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion_escolas">
    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="escola in inscricao.Escolas">
        <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#escola{{ $index }}" data-parent="#accordion_escolas">
            <div class="panel-title">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                {{ escola.Nome }} <span class="text-muted">x alunos inscritos</span>
                <span class="pull-right text-muted expandir"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="escola{{ $index }}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>
                    <label for="qtdProfessoresEscola{{ $index }}">Qtd. Professores</label><br />
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="qtdProfessoresEscola{{ $index }}}}" value="{{ escola.QtdProfessores }}" />
                </p>
                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion_escola{{ $index }}">
                    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="serie in escola.Series">
                        <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#turma_{{ $index }}_escola{{ $parent.$index }}" data-parent="#accordion_escola{{ $parent.$index }}">
                            <div class="panel-title">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                                {{ serie.Nome }} <span class="text-muted">y alunos inscritos</span>
                                <span class="pull-right text-muted expandir"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="turma_{{ $index }}_escola{{ $parent.$index }}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Turma</th>
                                            <th>Qtd Alunos</th>
                                            <th>Qtd Testes A3</th>
                                            <th>Alunos PCD</th>
                                            <th></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr ng-repeat="turma in serie.Turmas">
                                            <td>{{ turma.Nome }}</td>
                                            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{ turma.QtdAlunos }}" /></td>
                                            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{ turma.QtdTestesA3 }}" /></td>
                                            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{ turma.AlunosPCD }}" /></td>
                                            <td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button">Excluir Turma</button></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <p>
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Adicionar Turma</button>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js/app.js:

```
/* js/app.js */
'use strict';

(function () {
    var provasNaoIdentificadas = angular.module("provasNaoIdentificadas", [
        'restClient'
    ]);

    provasNaoIdentificadas.controller("accordionCtrl", ["$scope", "ListaInscricao", function($scope, ListaInscricao){
        $scope.inscricao = {
            "Secretaria": ""
        };

        $("accordion-list").on("hidden.bs.collapse shown.bs.collapse", ".collapse", function (event) {
            if ($(this).hasClass("in")) {
                $(this).prev().find(".glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-minus");
                $(this).prev().find("span.pull-right.text-muted").removeClass("expandir fechar").addClass("fechar");
            } else {
                $(this).prev().find(".glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-plus");
                $(this).prev().find("span.pull-right.text-muted").removeClass("expandir fechar").addClass("expandir");
            }

            console.log(1, this, event);
        });

        ListaInscricao.get({"id": 1}, function(data){
            if (data.Sucesso) {
                $scope.inscricao = data.Dados;
            } else {
                // toastr
            }
        });
    }]);

    provasNaoIdentificadas.directive('accordionList', function() {
        return {
            "restrict": "E",
            "templateUrl": "partials/accordion.html"
        };
    });
})();
```

js/rest-client.js:

```
/* js/rest-client.js */
'use strict';

(function(){
    var restClient = angular.module('restClient', ['ngResource']);

    restClient.factory('ListaInscricao', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('mock/lista_inscricao.json');
    }]);
})();
```

mock/lista_inscricao.json:

```
{
    "Sucesso": true
    ,
    "Mensagem": ""
    ,
    "Dados": {
        "Secretaria": "Secretaria de Educação ABC"
        ,
        "Escolas": [
            {
                "Nome": "Escola 1"
                ,
                "QtdProfessores": 12
                ,
                "Series": [
                    {
                        "Nome": "1º Ano Ensino Médio"
                        ,
                        "Turmas": [
                            {
                                "Nome": "A"
                                ,
                                "QtdAlunos": 30
                                ,
                                "QtdTestesA3": 0
                                ,
                                "AlunosPCD": "27,29"
                            }
                            , {
                                "Nome": "B"
                                ,
                                "QtdAlunos": 28
                                ,
                                "QtdTestesA3": 2
                                ,
                                "AlunosPCD": ""
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                    ,
                    {
                        "Nome": "2º Ano Ensino Médio"
                        ,
                        "Turmas": [
                            {
                                "Nome": "A"
                                ,
                                "QtdAlunos": 25
                                ,
                                "QtdTestesA3": 1
                                ,
                                "AlunosPCD": "7"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
            ,
            {
                "Nome": "Escola 2"
                ,
                "QtdProfessores": 10
                ,
                "Series": [
                    {
                        "Nome": "3º Ano Ensino Médio"
                        ,
                        "Turmas": [
                            {
                                "Nome": "A"
                                ,
                                "QtdAlunos": 30
                                ,
                                "QtdTestesA3": 0
                                ,
                                "AlunosPCD": "15,27"
                            }
                            , {
                                "Nome": "B"
                                ,
                                "QtdAlunos": 26
                                ,
                                "QtdTestesA3": 0
                                ,
                                "AlunosPCD": ""
                            }
                            , {
                                "Nome": "C"
                                ,
                                "QtdAlunos": 25
                                ,
                                "QtdTestesA3": 0
                                ,
                                "AlunosPCD": ""
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it collapsing on the page? Are you sure the event is fired?

Comment: it is collapsing, but the event is not logged in the console and it is not changing the collapsible icon when it closes the accordion

Comment: I think your problem is in your html code. Can you post it or make a fiddle?

Comment: done :) I've posted the code

Comment: It's an old question but I've used the MutationObserver to listen to class changes on both the target as the trigger. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Answer (score 10, accepted):

for now, I've just changed my event listener. For some reason, jquery can't hear the hidden.bs.collapse. I've noticed that the click event is not suitable for this case, because if you click fast enough, you can end with a closed accordion and a minus icon on it. So, I've changed the event listener to:

```
$(document).on("hide.bs.collapse show.bs.collapse", ".collapse", function (event) {
    $(this).prev().find(".glyphicon").toggleClass("glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus");
    $(this).prev().find("span.pull-right.text-muted").toggleClass("expandir fechar");
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

This is working pretty well. But, as bhantol said, it not quite the angularjs way of doing things. The one with a better solution win the prize xD

Comment: Does this question provide a pure CSS way of doing what you are trying to do?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18568997/1745738

Answer (score 6):

We don't use jquery code in Controllers.

Controllers are not the right place for DOM manipulation.

Directives are what you need for DOM manipulation.

Also in AngularJS we generally don't use jQuery eventing programming style.

Here is approximate plunker of your [orignial code](http://plnkr.co/edit/6WPr7tjpdhvdpljlCdlG?p=preview). If I understand correctly you re trying to toggle the state of glyphicon state + and - using the code below:-

```
$("accordion-list").on("hidden.bs.collapse shown.bs.collapse", ".collapse", function (event) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("in")) {
        (this).prev().find(".glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-minus");
        $(this).prev().find("span.pull-right.text-muted").removeClass("expandir fechar").addClass("fechar");
    } else {
        $(this).prev().find(".glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-plus");
        $(this).prev().find("span.pull-right.text-muted").removeClass("expandir fechar").addClass("expandir");
    }

    console.log(1, this, event); // i have detected the problem by interpreting 
 });
```

Click [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/eJnjNq?p=preview) for the solution plunker.

The solution is all in accordion.html notice `ng-model` however I hace commented out your jquery code in the controller.

```
ng-model="collapseState"
```

this is to hold the state.

then further notice

```
<span class="glyphicon" 
    ng-class="collapseState[$index] ? 'glyphicon-minus' : 'glyphicon-plus'">
</span>
```

here we choose the class based on the value of `collapseState[$index]`.

Also notice ng-click which basically toggles the value of `collapseState[$index]`

```
ng-click="collapseState[$index]= !collapseState[$index]"
```

So far what we have done is used a model and altered the view by manipulating the model. 
This is the gist of AngularJS way.

Comment: I figured out that the click event is not suitable for this case, because if you click fast enough, the icon will finish with minus when the collapsible is closed.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to make angular listen to custom events, this is the real problem. Then i forced myself to use jquery DOM manipulation.

Comment: and +1 for your attention ;)

Comment: @andre Wondering if you have given a thought about angularui-bootstrap project. They bridge the angularjs and bootstrap very well and the accordion is an existing widget. http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion