# Bootstrap collapse within a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble getting the collapsible panels to work within my foreach loop.  When an item is clicked, all of the items expand/retract, which isn't what I want.  I want each element to be independent.

I am connected to a database and basically want to display the data simply and be able to expand to see more information.

I've tried lots of different solutions, my current method is based off https://stackoverflow.com/a/18568997/1366033
What should I do about the id and href?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    foreach (var item in groupItem){

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                        <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel1">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne"
                                       href="#collapseOne">
                                       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                                    </a>
                                </h4>

                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                                <div class="panel-body">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IdNumber)
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
```

Comment: `id` should be a unique value per document. You put `id="accordion"` in a loop so you kind of breaking that rule.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically you are creating panel with loop and assigning the same `id` to all the `panel-group` and that's what causing the problem here! So you can try working as below and please note `ids` should be unique in DOM

```
@{int i=0;}
foreach (var item in groupItem)
{
       <div class="panel-group" id="accordion_@i">
              <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel_@i">
                     <div class="panel-heading">
                           <h4 class="panel-title">
                                 <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne_@i" href="#collapseOne_@i">
                                       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                                  </a>
                            </h4>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapseOne_@i" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IdNumber)
                            </div>
                      </div>
              </div>
        </div>
        i++;
}
```

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Comment: @sumedha.. No probs.. Happy coding.. :)

Comment: Can you please explain what does @ mean?

Comment: @mamadgiaishwarya Its basically Asp.net MVC syntax for boilerplate UI with dynamic contents from backend.. :)

Comment: @mamadgiaishwarya Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Comment: In Laravel no need for the extra iteration just replace the id with the dynamic groupItem  id, e.g {{$groupItem->id}}.