# FAQ page markup with bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Trying to select some markup from bootstrap 3 to create a page with FAQs. I'm looking at panels(http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels) but it's not a best solution. Any ideas about how to apply bootstrap 3 elegantly at FAQ page?
it seems that it's better to look for something in html5 tags

Comment: [Bootstrap Accordion Group](http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/2015/06/bootstrap-accordion-group.html)

Comment: Thank you, Sender. But I'm using bootstrap 3

Comment: Yes it's bootstrap 3. [check it out in css](http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/xXAr5/light/)

Comment: Use the accordion and panels like this: http://bootply.com/aZOg5CjuAk

Comment: Also answered in this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325779/bootstrap-3-collapse-show-state-with-chevron-icon). And [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) the official bootstrap documentation for collapse.